# Code Igniter and PHP CLI

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line, command-line-interface

Has anyone had a problem with PHP CLI and CI 2.02?  I recently switched hostings and now whenever i try to execute

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/userName/public_html/index.php controllerName functionName
```

I get a blank output, it does not even seem like it executes the function since I have a echo statement in there.
If I execute a simple file I created, it works OK.

I don't know if it is something that needs to be changed in PHP or Apache config.

Comment: Try turning up the PHP error reporting level?

Comment: It seems like one of the setting that needed to run in the current environment was setup wrong.  The PHP error log helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that URI was not being passed and my site had the errors turned off so I could not see any of the error messages.  After getting the Error Logs turned on I was able to see I had the wrong URI set.